# Spacing bars in a bar chart using Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services

I have 3 series in a bar chart made in Report Builder 3. For example: column 1 Pitch Nights sold 10, Capacity 50, Occupancy 20% and I have 5 lots of results based on years.

When I run the report the bars in the chart are right next to each other (touching), but I want to space them out so it looks neater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are limited options here but you might get what you want.  From the view ribbon enable Properties.  Then select your Chart Series.  The property to experiment with is CustomAttributes / PointWidth.